# Multiple slideshows triggered by clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The goal is to have many slideshows on one page, each of which are hidden, but can be activated by clicking a related link. The first one should display and start cycling through its images once the page has loaded. Clicking a different link should activate it's related slideshow and hide the original one. The same should happen for any subsequent links/slideshows — showing only one slideshow at a time, relative to the link that was clicked — while all the other slideshows are hidden until their related link is clicked.

Here's a JSfiddle of where I'm at:

https://jsfiddle.net/9b20o33s/

There would be a chunk of code to paste here, but stackoverflow seems adamant about me pasting some code if I want to include a JSfiddle link, so here's my current slideshow script:

```
// JavaScript Document

$(function(){


var slideshow_class_array = [];
var slideshow_divs;
var temp_id;
slideshow_divs = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow_container');
$slideshow_obj_array = $.makeArray(slideshow_divs);
$('.slideshow_container').hide();

$.each($slideshow_obj_array, function(){

    $class_holder = this.getAttribute('name');
    slideshow_class_array.push($class_holder);

});

$('.slideshow_link').click(function(){
    for (var i=0; i < slideshow_class_array.length; i++ ) {

        temp_id = this.id.toString();
        temp_class = slideshow_class_array[i].toString();

        if ( temp_id === temp_class ) {

            $('div[name]').hide();
            $('div[name="'+temp_id+'"]').show();
            $('div[name] ul').hide();
            $('div[name="'+temp_id+'"] ul').show();                 
            $('div[name="'+temp_id+'"] .slideshow_fader img:gt(0)').hide();

            setInterval(function(){

              $('div[name="'+temp_id+'"] .slideshow_fader :first-child').fadeOut()
                 .next('div[name="'+temp_id+'"] .slideshow_fader img').fadeIn()
                 .end().appendTo('div[name="'+temp_id+'"] .slideshow_fader');},
              4000);

            } else { 

                $('div[name]').hide();

        }

    }

});

});
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: No images, but it looks like the functionality can still be tested with the icons that appear in place...

Comment: The first and second links aren't working right, while the third one is. But if I click the third link over and over, the set-interval timer seems to increase exponentially, and the slideshow turns into a bad trip. I may be figuring something out though...just keep on keepin' on as they say.

Comment: Progress...I was missing a break statement in my main for loop.

Comment: Updating the JSfiddle as I go. Seems to be something with the timer. As the links are subsequently clicked, the time interval between image fade transitions is getting a little screwy, but otherwise it seems to be working okay now.

Comment: Fixed. My problem was, as I mentioned above, I was missing the break statement after my loop, AND...I wasn't resetting the setInterval timer each time a new link was clicked.